# Can Mathematica calculate the triple integral $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

A recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3303563/9464) in Mathematics Stack Exchange *claims* that one can get from Mathematica the following result:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{32}.
$$

However, I am not able to reproduce the result with Mathematica 11. With the code

`Integrate[1/(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2,{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1}]`

I only got:

> [image]

With WolframAlpha, one has a numerical result:

> [image]

**Question**: Can Mathematica calculate the mentioned triple integral?

---

[Added later:]
According to what the author later added in his [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3303563/9464), he actually calculated the integral with Mathematica only *numerically*. Lele's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206098/664) below thus answers the question in the title: yes, the triple integral can be calculated, numerically. I am also curious to know though if Mathematica can return the result as $\dfrac{\pi^2}{32}$.

Comment: Please post the code you used to attempt to do this integral.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: it is nothing but one line and it is in the screen shot. Fair enough. I have now included it in the post. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Version 12 gives essentially the same answer, `Integrate[ArcCot[Sqrt[2 + x^2]]/((1 + x^2)*Sqrt[2 + x^2]), {x, 0, 1}]`.  I have no idea why the question was down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numerical integrations, you should use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`.

With

```
NIntegrate[1/(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

you obtain the same result as in WolframAlpha:

[image]

Comment: A symbolic answer appears to be desired.

Comment: Ok, the OP has changed the question now

Comment: @Lele: +1 Thanks for your answer and sorry for the ambiguity. I will try to find better way to edit my post.